# R Timezone from CEST (UTC+2) to UTC

Tags: r, datetime, timezone

**Questions about timezone attributions on R.**

**From CEST (UTC+2) to UTC**

There are some things that I do not get on R regarding the change of timezones.

Let's take an example.

```
datetime = as.POSIXct(paste(Sys.Date()-7,"00:00:00"), tz="CEST")
[1] "2018-04-04 CEST"
```

Let's recall that the timezone CEST stands for Central European Summer Time and is equivalent to UTC+2.

Knowing this, I want to assign the timezone UTC to my datetime. I am expecting to get "2018-04-03 22:00:00 UTC". Instead, this is what I get :

```
attr(datetime,"tzone") <- "UTC"
> datetime
[1] "2018-04-04 UTC"
```

Another thing is when I assign the timezone UTC+2 to my CEST datetime, I get the result I was looking for :

```
datetime2 = as.POSIXct(paste(Sys.Date()-7,"00:00:00"), tz="CEST")
[1] "2018-04-04 CEST"
attr(datetime2,"tzone") <- "UTC+2"
> datetime2
[1] "2018-04-03 22:00:00 UTC"
```

Though, since CEST is equivalent to UTC+2 I was expecting to get the result "2018-04-04 UTC".

**Does anyone understand the logic here?**

Comment: Don't use time zone abbreviations here.  Use [IANA time zone identifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).  For example, `tz="Europe/Paris"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the system time zone to UTC. Otherwise it will always automatically translate your time data to your local operating system time.

```
Sys.setenv(TZ='UTC')
```